# 2 column layout with 1 aspect ratio container and a full height div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a 2 column layout, with one column 2/3rds wide, and the second 1/3rd.

The first column should be taken up by a video container that maintains an aspect ratio of 4:3. I think I've done that correctly by setting the padding of the video container to 75%.

I'd like the 3rd column to contain a div that expands to the full height of the row. It doesn't seem able to.

I just wanted to ask if this was because the column layout gains its height from the video container (which in turn is based on it's width)? Or have I just overlooked something simple? I'd like to stop randomly adding 'height: 100%' to everything in the vague hope that it works and actually understand what I'm missing!

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-2-of-3">
      <div class="video-container">
        <div class="video">Column Containing 4:3 Video</div>    
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1-of-3">
      <div class="full-height-div">
        Div in column 2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.container {
  border: 1px dotted red;
}

.row {
  background: #aeaeae;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.row::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

[class^="col-"] {
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}
[class^="col-"]:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.col-1-of-3 {
  width: calc((100% - 2 * 10px}) / 3);
}

.col-2-of-3 {
  width: calc(((100% - 2 * 10px) / 3) * 2 + 10px);
}

.video-container {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 75%;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.video {
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}

.full-height-div {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px dotted #fff;
}
```

codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jxzMag?editors=1100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use flexbox instead of floats to create the layout: [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

By default, the elements in a flex row layout are stretched to 100% of the row height

Example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gzzvyO

```
.container{
  border: 1px dotted red;
}

.row{
  background: #aeaeae;
  display: flex;
}

.col-2-of-3{
  width: 67%;
  flex-grow: 0;
}

.col-1-of-3{
   flex-grow: 1;
   margin-left: 10px;
}

.video-container {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 75%;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%; 
}

.video{
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}

.full-height-div{
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px dotted #fff;
}
```

Comment: so is this not possible without flexbox? is it the fact that I'm floating the column that is causing the issue with height?

i could use flexbox, but i'm worried i'll have more issues as this is for a mobile design. that could be completely unfounded, but i'd also quite like to understand why this is happening. is it because i'm applying the clearfix to the row, which is after the 2nd column in the document flow?

Comment: In float layouts, you do not have the concept of rows or columns. The height of an floated element can not be set to 100% of it's parent's height. That is why we used the technique [Faux columns](https://alistapart.com/article/fauxcolumns) back in the old days.

Comment: It is unproblematic to use floats for mobile design. If you add `.row { flex-wrap: wrap; }` the elements will even wrap onto multiple lines, if the screen width is too narrow.